# how to Add new property to system class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
using System;

namespace Telerik.Windows.Controls
{
    public class Resource : IResource
    {
        public Resource();
        public Resource(string name);
        public Resource(string name, string type);

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string ResourceName { get; set; }
        public string ResourceType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to add a `public string NoOfAppointments { get; set; }` property to this class to customize Resource Class for my application.

How do i Achieve it ?

Can we define partial class of Resource,if We can how do i define?

After Adding new property I should use new **derived** or **partial** class as same as **Resource** Class.

Comment: Stecya +1. Maybe it would be great idea to deny such users from asking until they accept some of the answers given.

Comment: Stecya +1, but Ilya: This in turn would encourage people to accept answers that are not appropriate if they ask questions so difficult that they don't get any appropriate answers...

Comment: I'm not talking about 100% acc rate, but at least 50% after 100 asked seems reasonable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used staight forward way do it and its working.

```
    public class CustomResource: Telerik.Windows.Controls.Resource
    {
        private int noOfAppointments;
        public int NoOfAppointments
        {
            get { return noOfAppointments; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    noOfAppointments = value;
                else
                    noOfAppointments = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't working, or?

```
public class MyResource : Resource
{
    public MyResource();
    public MyResource(string name);
    public MyResource(string name, string type);

    public string NoOfAppointments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Pramod - what do you mean by 'telerik controls class'? Is it a sealed class?

Comment: Modify what? I didn't suggest modifying Resource, and looks like you ended up with the exact same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a property to an existing class. Partial classes won't help you because they're a *compile-time* feature for source files within the same project - you can't add to a class from a different assembly using partial classes.

You could derive a new class from `Resource`, as Marius has shown - but then everywhere that you get given just a `Resource`, you'd have to cast to the right type - and if the Telerik controls copy resource objects without noticing subclasses, that could cause problems. That may or may not *actually* be an issue for you - it's hard to say without knowing more about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I'm quite sure that the way you are going about it is incorrect. If you can tell more, what this Resource class is, how you used it and where the NoOfAppointments fits the picture, it would be easier to help.

Telerik is a third party library. It most cases, you can not change definition of classes inside a third party library. You also can not use partial classes for the classes from third party libraries. You can derive you classes from other classes and Marius Bancila just shown you how you do it in his answer. Note that he is not repeating the class from your question but rather defines a new class and specified that it is derived from it: `class MyResource : Resource`

But you can not force the library to use your class if it is hardwired to use its own class, so most likely deriving will not help you.